# Why variable is not being passed?

Tags: mysql, ajax, json, variables, jquery-select2

I am using select2 plugin to populate the tags from mysql.
So I am passing the q variable to the getdada.php.but the problem is that

1. q variable is not being passed to the getdata.php .I want to pass this variable so that i could get the data related to it(may be I am not placing the q variable at appropriate place.)

   2.if i dont use q variable,then only last or first variable is retrived.I want to populate all the results as tags data(perhaps error is in  my jsoncode formate in getdata.php)

Plz help.

```
        $("#e8").select2({


        placeholder: "Search for another Concept",
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        multiple: true,
        ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
            url: "getdata.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term, // search term

                      page: page

                };

            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return { results: data};

            }
        }
    });
```

here is the getdata.php

```
$sql=mysqli_query($db3,"SELECT * FROM o4_tags" );

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $tags=$row['tag_name'];
    $id=$row['id'];

        $myArray = array(
            array( "id" => "$id", "text" => "$tags" ),
        );


}

echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Comment: Just in case anybody needs this: Here's the Select2 he's talking about http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, there seems to be something going wrong with your PHP script. You are currently creating a new $myArray for every row retrieved. Only the last of these arrays is actually output as JSON. This code fixes that problem:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($db3,"SELECT * FROM o4_tags" );
$myArray=array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $tags=$row['tag_name'];
    $id=$row['id'];

    $myArray[]=array( "id" => "$id", "text" => "$tags" );
}
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

I'm not sure why you don't see the search term in your PHP script, but then again, I don't see any code in PHP that actually deals with a search term. Have you tried dumping $_REQUEST?

Comment: Thank u so much.I actually get the q value by using $q = $_GET["q"];